# VBA Excel Getting the Day from a Date

Tags: excel, vba, date, format, dayofweek

I have the following VBA Code that generates a list of dates, what I want is as I print out every date, to print the date in the format of day i.e. 01/10/2002 would be Monday:

```
Sub loopDates()
    Dim Stdt    As Date
    Dim Edt     As Date
    Dim n       As Date
    Dim c       As Long
    Stdt = Range("A1")
    Edt = Range("A2")
    For n = Stdt To Edt
            c = c + 1
            Range("C" & c) = n
            Range("B" & c).Formula = "=TEXT(C1,""dddd"")"
    Next n
End Sub
```

I want to change the line:

```
Range("B" & c).Formula = "=TEXT(C1,""dddd"")"
```

So that C1 in this example is change every time the loop is iterated, so it would change with the value c, for example it would look like =TEXT(C " & c &, "dddd") but I cannot get the formatting right,

Can anyone propose a solution to this problem?

Comment: What do you have in A1 and A2? In you example you fixed C1 to print date. Did you try Format(CELL, "dd/MM/yyyy")?

Comment: Answered it below, thanks for taking your time to look at the question, I was determined to answer it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to find from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251755.aspx) that you can just set the format of the cell. I changed the line mentioned in the original post to:

```
Range("B" & c) = Format(n, "dddd")
```

This takes the date from column and index of C and prints the day in the right format to the column and index of B

Thanks for answering